# How to model PostgREST database to achieve social-network-like behaviour

Tags: database, postgresql, postgrest

This question might have a super easy answer, but as I am new to PostgreSQL/PostgREST, I am not sure how to achieve it.

What I want to create is a schema/REST endpoint which allows me to query for posts posted by followed users.

Currently, the schema looks like this:

USERS

```
- first_name
, last_name
, id
```

POSTS

```
- id
, text
, author_id --foreign key to a user
```

CONNECTIONS

```
- id
, follower --foreign key to a user
, followed --foreign key to a user
```

I want to be able to query for the posts posted by users which given user follows, but I am not sure how to achieve this using postgREST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> posts posted by users which given user follows,

Try it like:

```
GET /posts?select=*,users!inner(connections!inner!followed(*))&users.connections.follower=eq.<your_user_id>
```

With that you'll get the `posts` you want though with some extra data.

Comment: You sir are a saint. I got it working by first fetching the list of followed ids and then fetching articles with follower=in.(<ids>), but I knew that it was not and ideal solution. This is awesome, thank you!